# Github Limits on number of remote refrence can be pushed (in x time span)?

Tags: git, github, limit, rate-limiting, git-lfs

I wrote a script to have multi-threads constantly push up new branches to a remote repo. Threads have no problems pushing up new branches for a bit then it would fail constantly.

if I set the script to create 100 branches with 50 threads. after 67 branches successfully pushed I start to get this failure.

```
 ! [remote rejected] 1558048813.14ConsumerThread-19 -> 1558048813.14ConsumerThread-19 (failure)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:my-org/my-repo.git'
```

If I decrease the number of threads (which means the pushes are more space out in between) or if I have threads sleep between pushes I get more successful pushes.

This leads me to suspect that Github has some kind of limits on number of pushes a user can do in X amount of time. (I am pushing via a deploy key with write access)? Does anyone know about this? if so, can you attach the source or doc that supports it?

---

by the way before each push I remove my `.git/hooks/pre-push` in the script because I was having an issue with git lfs. for some reason, my deploy key can't get access to my lfs endpoint. Not sure if that has anything to do with this.

Comment: I don't think it's documented. Ask Github support.